# How to integrate a website to paypal through javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, paypal

I want a website to be connected to paypal using javascript technology (I am using angularjs). I know that paypal provides a RESTFUL API, but there are lack of information of how to call those services. Can anybody provide me some good tutorial how this can be achieved ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with javascript alone , you will must have a server side implementation to achieve this.

That would include:

1. Generating a hash and maintaining a session for the request
2. Post the form fields with the generated hash to the Paypal server.
3. Have a return server side page where the response from Paypal is posted back
4. Verify the hash (posted back by Paypal) from your session.
5. Everything alright then redirect accordingly.